# change app caracteristics for different bundle identifier for iphone app

Tags: xcode, cocoa-touch, cfbundleidentifier

My idea is make an app and the PRO version of the same app.
but, instead of to make two different apps by xcode, is possible to give some features linked with the bundle identifier?

for example:

```
if (CFBundleIdentifierName==appPRO){
    }
```

(this is not working, of course..)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I found this that can help:

```
 NSString *bundleId = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] infoDictionary]objectForKey:@"CFBundleIdentifier"];
    if (! [bundleId isEqualToString:@"com.yourcompany.yourapp"])
    {
        // Ooops, CFBundleIdentifier doesn’t match
    }
```

That's not bad!

if you have any other idea, is accepted!